# A point on surface

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I make the following in tikz?
[image]

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates what you already tried and where your problems are. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=14cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x,\y,\z)=30+20*exp(-(\x*\x+\y*\y)/\z);}]
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,
    xmin=0,xmax=12.5,ymin=0,ymax=12.5,zmin=0,zmax=50,smooth,
    view={115}{20},
    xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,ztick=\empty,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,zlabel=$z$]
   \draw[dashed] (4.5,0,0)node[above left]{$x_0$} -- (4.5,4.5,0)
     -- (0,4.5,0) node[above right]{$y_0$}
     (4.5,4.5,0) -- (4.5,4.5,{f(4.5-4,4.5-4,8)});
   \addplot3[surf,fill=cyan,fill opacity=0.4,domain=0:8,domain
   y=0:8,samples=11,samples y=11,point meta=1] 
   {f(x-4,y-4,8)};
   \node[circle,inner sep=2pt,fill,
    label=above right:{$(x_0,y_0,z_0)$}] at (4.5,4.5,{f(4.5-4,4.5-4,8)}){};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]